# WP toolkit problem after deleting wordpress site manually

Tags: wordpress, plesk

I had a wordpress installation in my root folder. I create a /temp folder with a second wordpress installation to create and test a new version of my website. When finished, I used the All-in-one WP Migration plugin to create a backup of my /temp installation and restored that in the root. And I manually deleted the /temp folder.

All ok, but the problem is that WP Toolkit still shows 2 wordpress instances. And when I try to detach or delete the /temp version, I also get problems with the version installed in root.

Is there a way to manually check/edit the WP Toolkit data? I use Plesk.

Thanks for any help!